# Add Samples after Partial Training in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have trained a model in PyTorch - an RCNN for text classification. The model has very high precision and recall, but I may eventually receive new documents with text unlike what I used to train, validate, or test the model.

I would like to add new text samples to the model without retraining the model from the beginning. This is desirable because I may lose access to some of the text used for initial training.

If it is not possible to add samples (documents), is it possible to train a new model on only the new samples and then somehow combine the original model and the new model? How?

Here is what my model looks like.

```
RCNN(
  (embeddings): Embedding(10661, 300)
  (lstm): LSTM(300, 64, bidirectional=True)
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
  (W): Linear(in_features=428, out_features=64, bias=True)
  (tanh): Tanh()
  (fc): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=3, bias=True)
  (softmax): Softmax(dim=1)
  (loss_op): NLLLoss()
)
```

I am aware of techniques for saving the model and the corresponding load techniques.

- **State Dictionary:**`torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)`
- **Model:**`torch.save(model, PATH)`
- **Checkpoint:**`torch.save({'epoch': EPOCH, 'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(), 'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(), 'loss': LOSS,}, PATH)`

I can continue training based on the original samples, but I do not know how to add samples.

If this is something TensorFlow can do by PyTorch cannot, I might switch to TensorFlow.

Comment: Well, you can load your model's state from a file (*via* a checkpoint) and resume training *or* finetune on other data, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ivan, yes, I suppose I am looking to fine-tune on other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your model's state saved in some file `PATH`, you can load it back in memory with [`torch.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html#torch.load). Either on CPU or CUDA device, by default it will be loaded on the device it was on when `torch.save` was called).

```
state_dict = torch.load(PATH)
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

Assuming `model` is an instance of the same `nn.Module` class that was used to save the state on `PATH`. Now `model` will have an identical state (same parameter weights/biases) as when it was saved on `PATH` with `torch.save`. From there you can call `model` and finetune on new data.

Note: You can load it directly on the desired device by passing a [`torch.device`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.device) to `torch.load`'s `map_location` argument.

Comment: I understand how to save and load a model. My question is how do I go about fine-tuning with new samples.

Comment: It depends on your strategy: full finetune or finetuning certains layers of your model. Either way the finetuning process is pretty straight forward. You train your already model on new data. If you're using dataloaders, then you would go about creating a new dataset/dataloader for your new samples and train on them with epochs.

Comment: Then you would proceed with the same approach as when you initially trained your model. The only difference is you will have to load your model's state beforehand.